Firebase Remote Config - Does JSON value have a maximum size?
I'm trying to publish changes to a JSON variable, but I get an error when publishing “A general validation error occurred.”.
enter image description here
I suspect it is because of too long JSON, it has 11 thousand lines, a size 1.23 MB.
The problem is definitely not with formatting, a small part of this JSON is published without problems.
Maybe there is some size limit in Firebase?
Tried publishing a small part of this JSON, but no errors occurred

When it comes to Firebase Remote Config, the problem isn't about the number of lines but the number of characters that cannot exceed 1,000,000. So according to the official documentation regarding limits on parameters and conditions:

Within a Firebase project, you can have up to 2000 parameters, and up to 500 conditions. Parameter keys can be up to 256 characters long, must start with an underscore or English letter character (A-Z, a-z), and may also include numbers. The total length of parameter value strings within a project cannot exceed 1,000,000 characters.


Hey Buka. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
